# Error: undefined symbol: _ZNSt15__exception_ptr13exception_ptr10_M_releaseEv

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch, anaconda, importerror

I'm trying to run the code from this repository: https://github.com/RuojinCai/ShapeGF, was able to install all required dependencies from enviroment.yml and also installed cuda toolkit and nvidia drivers but at the moment python test.py configs/recon/ airplane/airplane_recon_add.yaml
--pretrained pretrained/recon/airplane_recon_add.pt error comes out of the header.
Ubuntu 22.04.2LTS
cuda 12.2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 98, in <module>
    main_worker(cfg, args)
  File "test.py", line 71, in main_worker
    trainer_lib = importlib.import_module(cfg.trainer.type)
  File "/home/roman/anaconda3/envs/ShapeGF/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/roman/Projects/ShapeGF/trainers/ae_trainer_3D.py", line 14, in <module>
    from evaluation.evaluation_metrics import EMD_CD
  File "/home/roman/Projects/ShapeGF/evaluation/evaluation_metrics.py", line 9, in <module>
    from evaluation.StructuralLosses import match_cost  # noqa
  File "/home/roman/Projects/ShapeGF/evaluation/StructuralLosses/match_cost.py", line 3, in <module>
    from evaluation.StructuralLosses.StructuralLossesBackend import ApproxMatch, MatchCost, MatchCostGrad
ImportError: /home/roman/Projects/ShapeGF/evaluation/StructuralLosses/StructuralLossesBackend.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt15__exception_ptr13exception_ptr10_M_releaseEv
```

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: These errors typically arise from mixing channels. Please detail more precisely (step by step) how the environment was created, so that others can recreate. Also, [start an Issue on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/RuojinCai/ShapeGF/issues).